# Gazebo Garden - How to get colliding entities with gpu_lidar sensor (ray)

Tags: gazebo, simulation, lidar

Good morning, I open this question as I have not found a way to get the `model_entity` that collides with the `gpu_lidar` sensor.

I would like to be able to attach a gripper with such entity, but I can't know its name and location a priori. The only info I have is the relative distance from the lidar sensor msg.

Is there any way to get the first mesh to collide with the ray of the gpu_lidar and subsequently trace back to the link to create a detachable joint?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Gabriele, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

From [your question at Gazebo Answers](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29341/how-to-get-colliding-entities-with-gpu_lidar-sensor-ray/) I understand that you want to move the gripper to the detected lidar position, and then grasp the object by making a detachable joint. But for this you need the entity ID of the detected object. Correct?

If so, you can probably use a PerformerDetector system with the PerformerDetector's region attached to your gripper. It publishes the name and the entity ID.

See [this documentation](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/e19f26d429c00dedabd596cd82344dbaedad3cc0/src/systems/performer_detector/PerformerDetector.hh#L40-L50) and the PerformerDetector [example world](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/performer_detector.sdf).

Comment: One caveat is that the PerformerDetector uses axis aligned boxes, so it may not work well in some cases. Another option to look at is [logical cameras](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/logical_camera_sensor.sdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference!
The difficulty really lies in making attachments with an entity whose location and ID I cannot know a priori, I would like to emulate the most realistic behavior possible and looking on the net I found only about vacuum gripper (not working) and I was looking for something that would narrow down the check on entities in a particular area of the gripper, and then make attachments with the closest one based on the lidar msg.

Comment: There are other possible solutions, e.g. transform the laser scanner object points into world coordinates, and compare these to object coordinates from a [pose publisher](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/pose_publisher.sdf) to discriminate which objects corresponds to the laser scanner detection. But as @Tully already wrote in another comment: you will need to give more detailed info on what specific you try to achieve (preferably with a sketch or image), how exactly you are currently trying, and what specific problems you run into that make it not work.